# Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed on x3850 x6 SLES12

Tags: kernel, kernel-panic, sles

We got a few new machines: x3850 x6.

All could pxe boot fine, except one machine, that gives the following kernel panic, looks like an exciting issue:

[image]

We cannot even scroll up after the kernel panic occurs, after 30-40 seconds. It hungs so bad, that I cannot even type anything.

**Anybody have any clue**, what could the problem possibly be? If it is a HW bug, then what to replace? CPUs? Motherboard?

- the BIOS settings are the exact same vs. working ones
- the firmware/bios versions are the exact same vs. working ones
- tried cold boot, the same kernel panic
- tried to boot with kernel parameters: "acpi=off" - it just did the same kernel panic at ~18 sec, not the usual panic at 30-40 sec.
- tried: "noapic nomodeset xforcevesa" - panic after 30-40 sec.
- tried: "acpi=off noapic nomodeset xforcevesa" - panic after 30-40 sec.
- tried: "isolcpus=0" boot param, same kernel panic, after 30-40 sec.
- tried to boot a slacko-5.6-PAE.iso - it **booted normally**! 3.10.5 SMP PAE. But we have to use SLES. The PAE kernel only sees ~65 GByte RAM, if that is a useful info.
- tried: https://www.memtest86.com/downloads/memtest86-iso.zip to run a simple memtest, but after 59 seconds of run without memory error, the machine freezed. -> UPDATE: The Memtest86+ from: http://www.memtest.org/#downiso doesn't freezes.

Once I seen: "Kernel panic - not syncing: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 18" - there are 4 CPUs in the machine, each has 18 cores, so don't know which one is this..

**UPDATE**: with the "maxcpus=0" kernel boot parameter, it finally booted, but still investigating, because still said: "A start job is running for Activation of LVM2 logical volumes (Xmin xs / no limit)" - **but maybe CPU HW issue?**

Comment: to scroll up try Shift-PageUp.

Comment: no, it doesn't work, but could record the full terminal with the IMM's recording solution, but nothing interesting there..

Comment: Is that really a panic? It looks like the machine has continued to run after the stack trace, so it may just be a recoverable error. Does the boot eventually complete or is it hung?

Comment: I think the memtest86 freezing is the nail in the coffin. That tools is basically a minimal OS which rules out this is just the OS.

Comment: Might be a stupid proposition but ... i already had a machine that won't even boot if a strange PS/2 mouse was connected to it. Did you try to boot with other peripherals ?
I suggest this as i see some message about your peripherals in the output log you provide us so ...

Comment: since it has 4 CPU sockets, i guess it is a server. Please check if you have IPMI SEL logs for that system, that will give more clue.

Comment: @jdwolf: "which rules out this is just the OS." - didn't you wanted to say, this is the HW?

Comment: @whoonetets it could also be a bug in BIOS/UEFI or bad configuration or a short on the USB bus if by hardware that would imply its not compatible hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an emulex card driver upgrade, it doesn't kernel panic any more.

Version 11.0.270.24 to 11.4.1186.3